# Teradata using CASE statement need to change the date format

Tags: date, format, case, teradata

I am calculating date using case
select a,b,c,
case when <condition 1> then x
when <condition 2> then y
end as date

i want the date to be of the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'
how do i set the format

Comment: The *client* formats a DATE, what's the datatype of `x` and `y`?

Comment: I think you need to make it a string if you want to format it to anything other than your locale setting.  Try `cast(cast (x as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD') as varchar(10))`